# Web Config ConnectionStringCollection limitations

Tags: asp.net, web-config

How many `connection strings` can you assign in the `web config`? Is this unlimited or not?

I need to hold many connection strings in a multi used application where every company has its own database ( sql server ).

Comment: How many are you expecting to store in the web.config?

Comment: For now I have around 10 customers that will use this application as a start. After that it can easily grow to a number of 50 till 100 or maybe more.

Comment: Why not store them in a database instead. Have one master connection string in the web.config and then lookup the correct connection string at runtime.  I wouldn't store them all in the web.config, especially if there are passwords exposed.

Comment: That was indeed my second thing I had in mind. I will look more into that then storing it all in the web config